# Filter records by current year in flow

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-flow-builder

I need to create a **flow** which retrieves all the accounts created **on the current year**. I am unable to write a condition on Lightning flows.
Is it possible to retrieve all the Accounts created on the current year using flows?

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing you can create a formula field on the account which is giving the Created Date year like YEAR(CreatedDate) and also create the formula in flow which is giving current year so you can easily check the condition while you are getting the records in flow.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I guess this should work